# Why is this first OCUnit unit test passing?

Tags: objective-c, ocunit

It should fail, but it's passing.  So I assume my syntax is wrong somewhere (although it builds).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FirstCocoaLibrary : NSObject

-(int)AddFirstNum:(int) i1 withSecondNum:(int) i2;

@end


#import "FirstCocoaLibrary.h"

@implementation FirstCocoaLibrary

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (int)AddFirstNum:(int) i1 withSecondNum:(int) i2{

    return i1 + i2;
}

@end

#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>
#import "FirstCocoaLibrary.h"

@interface FirstCocoaLibraryTests : SenTestCase{
    FirstCocoaLibrary *_adder;
}

@end

#import "FirstCocoaLibraryTests.h"

@implementation FirstCocoaLibraryTests

- (void)setUp
{
    // Set-up code here.
    _adder = [[FirstCocoaLibrary alloc] init];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Tear-down code here.

}

- (void)testExample
{
    //STFail(@"Unit tests are not implemented yet in FirstCocoaLibraryTests");
}

- (void)ShouldAdd2Numbers {

    int result = [_adder AddFirstNum:4 withSecondNum:5];
    STAssertEquals(0, result, @"Test Failed at adding", result);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCUnit only automatically runs methods whose names start with `test`. I don't think it's passing; it's not getting run at all. Rename `ShouldAdd2Numbers` to `testAddFirstNumWithSecondNum`.

Also note that Obj-C convention is for method names, and each section of a method name, to start with a lower-case letter. Thus, `addFirstNum:withSecondNum:`

Answer (score 2):

That test is probably not running at all. It should be called testShouldAdd2Numbers

BTW, your methods should start lowercase;

*EDIT*

This darn keyboard is slow. Do what @Josh Caswell said. :)

Comment: Haha! I win [again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8102107/)! :p (Seriously, though, we were about 30 seconds apart on this one. Upvotes for all!)

Comment: I'm going to have to buy me a physical keyboard for this iPad because of you! :) Yep, +1 on your better, faster, answer.

Comment: Well, you may take some satisfaction in my envy of your iPad. Haven't gotten one of those yet.