# NSTimer Pause timer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Pause/Play NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975562/how-to-pause-play-nstimer)

I have three buttons `start` `stop` and `pause`..My `start` and `stop` button is working fine with the below code..but when press `Pause` it pause the timer..but when again i Press start.IT continues from the new added time ...not from the pause time....

supoose i pause at  5 second of start and wait for 5 sec then press start...it should display 5 ...but displaying 10..

because I have not mentioned  `(timer:)` in `timer!=nill` of `start`...
how it will be add..

I have problems:

1. `Pause` not working.

```
-(void)start:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  if(_timer==nil)
  {
    startDate =[NSDate date];

    _timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(timer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  }

  if(_timer!=nil)
  { 
    float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];

    [_timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
  }

}

-(void)timer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  NSInteger secondsSinceStart = (NSInteger)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];

  NSInteger seconds = secondsSinceStart % 60;
  NSInteger minutes = (secondsSinceStart / 60) % 60;
  NSInteger hours = secondsSinceStart / (60 * 60);
  NSString *result = nil;
  if (hours > 0) 
  {
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];
  }
  else 
  {
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];        
  }

  label.text=result;

  NSLog(@"time interval -> %@",result);
}

-(void)stop
{
  if(_timer!=nil)
  {
    startDate=nil;

    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil; 
  }
}

-(void)pause:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];

  previousFireDate = [_timer fireDate];

  [_timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975562/how-to-pause-play-nstimer

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)pause:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];

  previousFireDate = [_timer fireDate];

  //[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
  [_timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

Comment: ya this works...this `pause` the timer..but when I again `Start` it would not start from pausestart...its keep on counting in backside...and displays the updated time not pause time

Comment: suppose i pause at 5 second and wait for 5 second then press start ..it displays me 10 sec not 5...

Comment: this is the only problem left now

Comment: i think i got the problem...bcz when i pause...then I am starting again from the start key..and have not given (timer:) in start for pause

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I used for a timer:

I store all the components for the time, in my (singleton) class, the hour, minute, seconds value.

And, I simply "invalidate" the timer in the "pause" method, AND I store the values.

See, if this helps.

```
-(void) startTimer
{
    NSLog(@"Values for timer: %d H, %d M, %d S", self.hours, self.minutes, self.seconds);

    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) pauseTimer
{
    if(_timer)
    {
        [_timer invalidate];
    }

    _timer = nil;

    self.hour = hourValue;
    self.minute = minuteValue;
    self.second = secondsValue;
}
```