# To start and pause NSTimer with button and show time in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a problem for pause timer i have take UIButton in my storyboard.first when button clicked timer start and when that button(who star timer) pressed again timer pause not stop. i don't want to stop my timer i just want to start and pause timer. e.g. when timer reach 2 min timer stop. I also want to show time running and pause in label.

Yes [How to Pause/Play NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975562/how-to-pause-play-nstimer) this link works for changing title for button but how to saw time in label.

Comment: i tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975562/how-to-pause-play-nstimer

Comment: but when i press button it reacts nothing and its title becomes ...

Comment: ok..its worked its changing title of button but i want to show timer result in label..